# Google Cloud Function not executing even when properly called from Google Cloud Scheduler HTTP Request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, python-3.9, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a google cloud function running Python 3.9. It has an HTTP endpoint that is called by a Google Cloud Scheduler job that is set to run once every minute of every weekday. The function sometimes runs as intended, being executed once every minute as you can see below at the start of the logs in the screenshot. However, seemingly without pattern it will start to execute at 6 minute, 3 minute, or 2 minute intervals, where there are gaps in the Cloud function's logs where absolutely nothing happens, it doesn't even register a request from the scheduler.

However, if you compare the scheduler logs over the same time frame, it is sending the requests normally during this time, and almost every response is the same regardless of whether or not the Cloud function actually ran.

The code runs for an average of 2.5 seconds and a maximum of about 8 seconds, so there should not be any overlap between running code and a new scheduler request coming in.

The auth header of the scheduler job is an OIDC token pointing to an IAM service account that has full access to both Scheduler and Cloud Function execution privileges.

**Cloud Function Logs:**
[image: Cloud Function logs]

**Cloud Scheduler Logs:**
[image: Cloud Scheduler logs]

Comment: Can you share your code, or a minimal piece to reproduce the same thing and help you more?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere If I do that it would take a while to create a minimal piece to reproduce the code as it's quite long. However, I wouldn't think this has anything to do with the code itself since the logs don't show the code starting at all during the gaps. I think this has something to do with the interaction between Google Cloud Scheduler and the HTTP endpoint.

Comment: In this case, I can't debug Google Cloud!! Ask the support for help!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I already have! I don't expect much more from them unless I pay for enterprise level support, even then there's no guarantee. At that point I should just consider running my program inside a VM with some sort of cron scheduling library, which isn't a big deal. However, it's frustrating how inexplicable this problem is.

Comment: Report issues and request features with issue trackers which are free. https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers